# Dot & swap numbers

Tags: amsthm

I wanted to have something like `1.1.1. Theorem` and not `Theorem 1.1.1.`
So i used `\swapnumbers` to do it, but it gives me `1.1.1 Theorem`.

I just want to add a dot after the theorem/definition number.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.05}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\setcounter{section}{1}  
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}[subsection]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[subsection]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollaire}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Définition}[subsection] 

\begin{document}
\begin{thm} 
Il y avais une fois \dots
\end{thm}
\begin{mydef} 
Il y avais une autre fois \dots
\end{mydef}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm pretty sure we can help, but we need to see how you generate/format the theorems (which package, which settings etc). Please provide the code of a small compiling document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows the problem.

Comment: I add the code :)

Comment: Please add not only the preamble, but a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a sample document body to your code. I've also streamlined the preamble slightly.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a better solution than patching the macro responsible for typesetting this part of the theorem.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\swappedhead{~}{.~}{}{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\swappedhead{~}{.~}{}{}
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{thm}
  Sometimes 2 plus 2 does not add up to 4.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

After having seen how to obtain what you want, maybe reconsider whether this is a good design decision. My advice from some decades of writing theorems and such:

- Make the numbers short, to make them easier to remember. Having to remember whether it was theorem 1.2.1 or lemma 1.1.2 is an unnecessary burden. For an article, there is no need to number within sections, subsections etc.
- To help finding the theorem, lemma, example etc, use the same counter for *all* theorem-like environments. This way you will have a constant stream of numbered environments, and it is not hard to locate example 4 between lemma 3 and theorem 5.

In your current numbering scheme, you will have

> **1.1.1. Theorem**

and

> **1.1.1 Some subsubsection**

side by side, with more or less the same font size. This may be confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! For the section it's possible to ad it with the package titlesec !

Comment: Yep i don't know if it's a good option i just find the design of a book very nice ! (Calvage&Mounet edition)

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do with `thmtools`, which cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem`. Here are two examples, one with the theorem number at the left margin, the other with the number in the left margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{ geometry}%
 \usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}%
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, % spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=.5em, %
headformat=\NUMBER.~\NAME\NOTE%
]{plainswap}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, % spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=.5em, %
headformat={\llap{\NUMBER.~}\NAME\NOTE}
]{plainmarginno}

\declaretheorem[style=plainswap, numberwithin=subsection, name=Theorem]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=plainmarginno, sibling=thm, name=Theorem]{marginthm}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}

\begin{thm}
  Sometimes 2 plus 2 does not add up to 4.
\end{thm}

\begin{marginthm}
  Sometimes 1 plus 1 does not add up to 2.
\end{marginthm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get the dot after the Theorem number, but have document wide numbering, that is, only 1, 2,3, ...

Comment: @Paul: in `\declaretheorem[...]`, remove `numberwithin=subsection`.

Comment: Thx Bernard: My problem is that I use some template in the background and somehow my file gets destroyed with your solution. (Although I tested it and it works very well outside of my file) Is there an option to write this "." directly into the declare theorem? "\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Theorem,
]{theo}"  If I write the headformat directly in the \declarethoerem it says it does not know the headformat

Comment: Are there any messages about  thmtools in the .log file?